# Как получить событие ответа на звонок?

Tags: java, android

Каким образом можно получить факт соединения звонка, то есть тот момент когда человек на другой линии взял трубку.

Осуществимо ли это?

Просто если чисто на программно уровне то да. Потому что во время соединения мой телефон вибрирует. А значит что какой - то сигнал поступает...

Comment: Судя [по всему](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=14266) - нет

Comment: @LEQADA, тут написано вроде что можно
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5497061/detecting-outgoing-call-and-call-hangup-event-in-android

Comment: Хм, странно. Статус issue не обновили, а просто навесили "устарело". Вы попробовали уже так, как по ссылке говорится?

Comment: @LEQADA, да. Но почему то CALL_STATE_RINGING не работает

Comment: А, это кажется событие вашего ответа на звонок. Вам ведь не это нужно?

Comment: @LEQADA, неа. А как быть тогда? но блин ведь у меня вибратор включается когда звонок на конце телефона принимают

Comment: Без понятия. Этот вопрос и на английском SO открыт уже не первый год. Судя по всему, решения просто нет.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Нет, то что вы хотите сделать, насколько мне известно, даже в последней версии Android недоступно.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, тут дело не в телефоне и его программном обеспечении, а в телефонии как таковой — просто не предусмотрено никаких «спецсигналов» для извещения звонящего о том, что абонент ответил.

Comment: Скорее это вопрос безопасности.